# Extend celery.schedules.schedule to control task execution

Tags: task, celery, extend, schedule

I am trying to extend the celery.schedules.schedule to be able to control if a task should be executed or not.
Actually, I want to add two new args to the object (exclude_from and exclude_to) and prevent task from beeing executed between this hours.
I want to do that instead of using crontab because I need to execute tasks every minutes at a different second to limit charge.

I tried to do it in the is_due function but It is only partially working, because of the return of the function that should be (is_due 'True/False', 'next').

When I set next to 60 sec, it seems that celery never checks again.

Do you know why ? Is this the good place where to prevent task from beeing executed ?

Thank you for your help.

As an example :

```
    schedstate = namedtuple('schedstate', ('is_due', 'next'))

    hour = datetime.now().hour

    # now().hour must be oustide exclude_to and exclude_from else we prevent the execution
    if self.exclude_to > self.exclude_from:
        # In a case like exclude from 19h to 21h
        # we have to check exclude_from <= now().hour < exclude_to
        if self.exclude_from <= hour and hour < self.exclude_to:
            # raise Exception(schedstate(is_due=False, next=self.seconds))
            last_run_at = self.maybe_make_aware(last_run_at)
            rem_delta = self.remaining_estimate(last_run_at)
            remaining_s = max(rem_delta.total_seconds(), 0)
            return schedstate(is_due=False, next=remaing_s) # or next=60 does not work either
```

Louison

Comment: I still think this can be achieved using crontab. If you for example want to run your task every minute but excluding certain hours, you can use `minute="*"`, `hour="0-19,21-23"`. Or did I understand your requirement incorrectly?

Comment: Yeah sorry I may not be very clear.
I'm currently using crontab, but we can only execute task every minutes and I have to execute some of them every 30s for exemple. That is why need to find another way.